# How do I populate a list<> from SQL and display list values in a gridview

Tags: c#, list, gridview

I need to populate List using SQL and then Display values in a gridview. I think I am very close but for some reason the code below it's not working. I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Hello, I combined your solutions and I am getting all the values in one long column, and no headers. Any ideas? thank you!

```
    List<String> valuesList = new List<string>();
        String queryString = "Select NRCode__c,Amazon_Listing_Level__c, Amazon_Rule_ID__c,ESTShipPrice__c from vendors";
        SqlDataReader dr = classdb.LoadReader(queryString) as SqlDataReader;

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(1));
                valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(2));
                valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(3));
            }
            dr.Close();

            Label1.Text = "works";
        }
        else
        {
            dr.Close();
            Label1.Text = "No working";
        }


        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = valuesList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
   }
 }
```

Comment: explain:  _not working_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace This:

```
        dr.Read();
        valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(0));
        valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(1));
        valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(2));
        valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(3));
        dr.Close();

        Label1.Text = "works";
```

With This:

```
        while(dr.Read())
        {
         valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(0));
         valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(1));
         valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(2));
         valuesList.Add(dr.GetString(3));
        }
        dr.Close();

        Label1.Text = "works";
```

Comment: This is working but the grid view is displaying all the records in one long column, how can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are just giving it a simple list of strings, so it is going to just give you all those strings in a single column.  If you want multiple columns, you need a DataTable.  Check the answer provided by @mellamokb.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- The data source of a gridview should be the entire collection. Your loop is overwriting the data source over and over again. Try `GridView1.DataSource = valuesList`.
- Also, if you simply want to pull data from a database and display in a grid without making any changes to it, you can simplify greatly by using a `SqlDataAdapter` and writing to a `DataTable`:

Example:

```
String queryString = "Select NRCode__c,Amazon_Listing_Level__c, Amazon_Rule_ID__c,ESTShipPrice__c from vendors";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString);
DataTable results = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(results);

GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
GridView1.DataSource = results;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you Mellamokb, I have to do it this because after I have this working i will use the list to make a connection to Salesforce Objects

Comment: You can use the contents of `results` later on to integrate with other systems.

Comment: Mellamokb, Thank you.. I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.Count; i++)
{

    GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    GridView1.DataSource = valuesList[i];
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

You need to get rid of the for loop.  The data source should just be valuesList.

```
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
GridView1.DataSource = valuesList;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are also looping through your values and you keep adding them as a datasource.
change this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.Count; i++)
    {

        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = valuesList[i];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

to be:

```
  GridView1.DataSource = valuesList;
  GridView1.DataBind();
```